# Run cat command in another dir

Tags: linux, sh, raspbian

In a shell script I run `cat` and `ffmpeg` to make some nice videos from a collection of .jpg images. I have the script in one directory and the pictures in a different directory depending of date. But I cant get it to work, this is what I have so far. It works if I run it in the same directory as the pictures. (Without the directory change as part of the command)

```
YEAR=`/bin/date +%Y`
DAY=`/bin/date +%d`
MONTH=`/bin/date +%m`

/home/pi/ftp/files/camera01/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/ cat *.jpg | \
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1 -i - -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p \
-r 25 /home/pi/ftp/files/camera01/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/today.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the directory prefix in the filename argument, not before the `cat` command.

```
cat /home/pi/ftp/files/camera01/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/*.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1 -i - -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -r 25 /home/pi/ftp/files/camera01/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/today.mp4
```

Or you could just `cd` to that directory, then you don't need to use the directory prefix at all.

```
cd /home/pi/ftp/files/camera01/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1 -i - -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -r 25 today.mp4
```